# Flask simple render_template implementation fails

Tags: python, flask

I’m trying to make a flask site and so far it’s working to print a hello world. When I try and turn from outputting text to outputting a simple html template the site breaks and I get the error below.

This is my code:

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

recipes_blueprint = Blueprint('recipes', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@recipes_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
     return    
render_template('list.html')
```

And my list.html is simply the below inside the templates folder:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

The full error is here:

```
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:     from app import app as application  # noqa
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399: 
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:   File "/home/jameshiven/mysite/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:     from products.views import products_bp
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399: 
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:   File "/home/jameshiven/mysite/products/views.py", line 12, in <module>
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:     render_template('list.html')
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399: 
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
2021-10-16 07:50:53,399:     ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
2021-10-16 07:50:53,400:
```

Comment: In the error we see ` render_template('list.html')` while in the code snippet we cant see it. Looks like you are mixing the code snippet with another error

Comment: Balderman - thank you for following up! Good observation, apologies actually that’s just just my fault rewriting the error on stackoverflow, the html is on the server correctly under list.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blueprints are supossed to be registered with flask app to be appeared in the app.

Modify your code to

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, Flask

recipes_blueprint = Blueprint('recipes', __name__, template_folder='templates')
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(recipes_blueprint)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('list.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Some examples [here](https://itnext.io/flask-blueprints-complete-tutorial-to-fully-understand-how-to-use-it-767f7433a02e), [here](https://realpython.com/flask-blueprint/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the actual exception message, but I'm going to guess it was:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

This is because your view function is messed up. Change it to say:

```
@recipes_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('list.html')
```

Then register your blueprint with the `app` object like John suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was as simple as the line break breaking it as you suggested